# Why can't I add this custom Node PATH to /etc/profile.d scripts?

Tags: bashrc, profile, node.js

I may have a problem in the include chain for the profiles, or something may be awry in either my system, or my understanding of profile.d (RHEL7).

I added a `/etc/profile.d` `.sh` script which is for a node installation, whilst trying to clean up the .bashrc.  The problem is that it is not appending to the `$PATH` like I had hoped.

Note, the issue is happening both via my main terminal (ssh via putty), but also directly from the console itself as well.

```
$ cat ~/.bash_profile
#
# .bash_profile
#
# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

---

```
$ cat /etc/profile.d/nvm_path.sh
# This adds node/nvm(node version manager) to path, and then initializes nvm, and its bash completion

#Load NVM
if [ -f ~/.nvm ]; then

    export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
    [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"

    if [ -f $NVM_DIR/bash_completion ]; then

        [ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
    fi
fi

# Force npm onto the path (only needed if its not available on your node installation)
if [ -f ~/.npm/ ]; then
    PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.npm
fi

# Include node_mod bins in PATH, which are usually symlinked here (gulp,
# cordova, etc..)
if [ -f $HOME/.npm-packages/bin ]; then

    #note is a hyphen, not an underscore
    PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.npm-packages/bin
fi

export PATH
```

For `/etc/profile` itself, its my understanding the perms are ok as read-only since they are sourced, as opposed to executed, so i think this isnt an issue. `-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1795 May  4  2016 profile`

What have i missed?

I'm thinking the problem is somewhere along the lines of since the scripts are initially loaded by root the paths are invalid.  The problem: where I try to load the user paths.  What can be done about this?  Do I need to add in a $LOGGED_USER variable in place of `if [ -f ~/.nvm ]` and maybe even `$HOME?`  What is that variable?

After further research, it appears the problem is that root is loading the script, so $HOME, even $USER, is never available, even if I set a condition in there to check if root is loading or not, since root is always sourcing the script.

```
e.g. 
if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
    USERDIR=$HOME
else
    USERDIR=/home/$USER
fi

if [ -f $USERDIR/.nvm ]; then
#...
```

I would need to have the var check happen once the user logs in, not when root sources it.

It appears something like this is destined for /etc/skel/.bash_profile, unless someone comes up with a clever bash script idea. Any ideas on how to accomplish this here, so that I don't have to use /etc/skel?

Comment: Does that `NVM_DIR` variable get set properly? Check that you don't have some other place in the shell's init scripts that would reset `PATH`.

Comment: Good call. Wouldn't I check jsut check that using `$ env`?  I see no mention of it. Do you think its because of the `-f ~/.nvm` doesn't exist for root since I'm checking it against user "`~`"?

Comment: -f checks for a regular file, -d checks for a directory.

Comment: Ok, that solved it.  I thought it was the file check at first, just didn't catch that. Add as an answer please.  Maybe just copy and paste my whole script there, and correct to the -d since it seems really useful for node path drop-in solution.  `$ which gulp
~/.npm-packages/bin/gulp`